# Fedora KDE 39 only sleeps once on lid close

Tags: fedora, kde, suspend

The first time I close my laptop lid it goes to sleep as expected. After waking it, all subsequent lid closes do absolutely nothing.

Any idea how to fix this? I have no idea where to start. I am using `tlp`, and have set sleep mode to `deep` in GRUB.